# For-Loop Definition in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm new to the Matlab. Can anyone explain for me why:

> If a for loop starts with for i = 1:0, then the body can only execute once.

Thank you.

Comment: it defines a sequence 'StartNumber:EndNUmber' in steps of size 1. The rather complete definition is `StartNumber:stepSize:EndNumber`. From 1 to 0 doesn't create a sequence but just the starting value. If you want to go backwards, use `1:-1:0`. Have a look at the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) they are pretty good in MATLAB. It is best to ask questions at stackoverflow if you have really a coding problem rather than looking for a lesson on the fundamentals

Comment: We cannot explain _why_ the quoted statement is true, because it is not true. `1:0` is empty, so the body will execute _zero_ times

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mention the step increment/decrement in `for` loop in MATLAB by default it will always take it as increment by 1.
For example

```
for i=1:3
disp(i)
end
```

It will print `i` three times i.e. `1 2 3`

For below example it will print nothing as condition already becomes false

```
for i=1:0
disp(i)
end
```

For step more than 1 or negative increment (decrement) you have to mention it explicitly as shown below

```
for i=1:2:6
disp(i)
end
```

it will print `1 3 5`

or

```
for i=1:-1:0
disp(i)
end
```

It will print `1 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `1:0` in the command window. The result will be "1×0 empty double row vector", which means this is an empty vector.
Perhaps what you were trying to achieve is the vector [1,0]. In this case, you should write explicitly `i = 1:-1:0`, which yields the correct result.

Comment: Or just write `i = [1,0]`.